# Implicitly converting int to double

Tags: c#, implicit-conversion

So, I'm a tad confused. I was under the impression that this should work:
In this case, both **a** and **b** are ints (Counters to be exact).

As the result of **a** / **b** may possibly contain decimal places, ints obviously won't work. 
Therefore, I delared a new double and performed the calculation inside it like this:

```
double texturefactor = ((a / b) * 10);
```

This doesn't work as I expected, and the result of **a** / **b** is always that which I would get if I performed the calculation using an int to store the results.
On the other hand, this works:

```
double calculate1 = a;
double calculate2 = b;
double texturefactor = ((calculate1 / calculate2) * 10);
```

Couple of perhaps stupid questions-
1. I'm sure this ought to work- I know that in certain situations VS will complain that I've tried to implicitly convert from one type to another- That's what I'm trying to do! Why doesn't it, and have I missed something? :)
2. Should I just convert the counters a and b to doubles and save myself the trouble of the conversion, or is that trouble?

Comment: try `double texturefactor = (((double) a / b) * 10);`

Comment: You might have noticed before that "return value" doesn't matter. They can't be used to resolve the "proper" overload of a method either - hence why we can have a single `Write` method, but have to use `ReadInt16`, `ReadInt32` etc. Operator / overload resolving happens only based on operands, which in your case is `int` and `int`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression, including the types of subexpressions, is evaluated from inside to outside:

```
double texturefactor = ((a / b) * 10);
```

When the compiler analyses `a / b`, it has no idea that the result will later on be converted to `double`, so it just compiles the computation as an integer division.

Explicitly casting one of the two operands to `double` right there is enough to avoid that confusion:

```
double texturefactor = (((double)a / b) * 10);
```

Answer (score 3):

The result of `a / b` is another integer, so even if you do this, the damage has already been done:

```
double texturefactor = ((a / b) * 10);
```

Try casting one of your inner variables to a `double`:

```
var texturefactor = (( (double)a / b) * 10);
```

The result of `(double)a / b` will be a double, and you won't lose your fraction.

To answer your second question:

> Should I just convert the counters a and b to doubles

That'd work too. If you change those to `double`, then you wouldn't have to perform the above cast.

Answer (score 2):

When you have the expression `(a / b)`, the C# compiler ignores that it will later be assigned to a `double`. It focuses only on that expression, and sees `int / int`, so it uses [integer division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html). This means that your result is rounded down to the next integer before it's ever converted to a `double`.

You need to make sure C# treats the division as a division of `double`s, not `int`s, for example:

```
double texturefactor = (((double)a / b) * 10); // or
double texturefactor = 10d * a / b; // or
double texturefactor = 10.0 * a / b;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason this `double texturefactor = ((a / b) * 10);` not working is that all the parameters on the right hand side are of type `int` thus the calculations are being done in `int` not `double` as you think.

You can explicitly cast `a` or `b` to double. Like

```
double texturefactor = (((double) a / b) * 10);
```

In your second code since you defined `a` and `b` as double, now the calculations are done in double type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the int values to double:

```
int a = some_value;
int b = some_value;
double texturefactor = (double)a / b * 10;
```

Comment: it is enough to convert one operand to be of type double to get a double value. (double)a/b*10 will get the same result

Answer (score 0):

Integer division will not have decimal values just because you are assigning their values to a `double` variable.

If you want precision, then your second method is quite good.

```
double calculate1 = a;
double calculate2 = b;
double texturefactor = ((calculate1 / calculate2) * 10);
```

The above is good.

I will not advise you to cast it into `double` as there is some overhead to pay.

Answer (score 0):

> Therefore, I delared a new double and performed the calculation inside it like this:

Ah, no.

> double texturefactor = ((a / b) * 10);

Basic syntax. YOu declare a double (texturefactor). You assign it the result of a pure integer opeation - (a/b)*10

Due to precedences this is a/b (integer, throw away digits) times 10. THEN implicit converison.

Typical beginner mistake - but one MANY do.

You want a double arithmetic, make sure any of the elements is a double, like for example:

((double) a/b)*10

will do a floating piont conversion for all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Result of dividing two integers is **always** a integer. So you need to

```
double texturefactor = (((double)a / b) * 10);
```