# Cant show all decimal numbers C#

Tags: c#, parsing, math, double

I have a little method in C# with the purpose of solve this **base equation**:

[image: Base equation]

I´m giving *n* and *x* values manually

We are going to supose that **X** value is **3** and **n** value is **1**. If I evaluate the equation I got this result:

[image]
My problem is that the output is 0, **I tried to parse the result as well**, but still apearing 0.

The real result is **0.88888888** but in the program output I just got **0**.

Here is my code:

```
using System;

namespace Polinomio
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int x = 3;
            int n = 1;

            double result = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
                result += (double)(Math.Pow((x - 1) / 3, Math.Pow(2, i))) / Math.Pow(2, i);           
            }

            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong or what I´m missing, I will appretiate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change data types of your variable to double.

```
 double x = 3;
 int n = 1;

 double result = 0;

 for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
 {
      result += (Math.Pow((x - 1) / 3, Math.Pow(2, i))) / Math.Pow(2, i);
 }

 Console.WriteLine(result);
```

This will do the trick.

Take a look here: [Implicitly converting int to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23293879/implicitly-converting-int-to-double)  for implicit conversion precidence in C# code.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This woke up my curiosity... Do you know why does this happen?

Comment: @weirzetig29 You are doing Integer-Arithmetic, then cast to double. But you need to do Floating-Point arithmetic in the first place.

Comment: @Fildor Really interesting.

Comment: @weirzetig29 updated with the link you might be interested in to finalize the answer.

Comment: Probably would have worked even if you had written `result += (Math.Pow((x - 1.0) / 3, Math.Pow(2, i))) / Math.Pow(2, i);`

Comment: @Fildor yes, it will be the solution as well, for a reason of 1.0 is a double.